# TypeScript - Export and import modules

Tags: import, module, export, typescript

Ok, this is my files:

memberDB.ts

```
module MemberDB {
    interface Member {
        name: string;
        age: number;
        hobbies: string[];
    }

    class Database {
        private members: Member[];

        constructor(first ? : Member) {
            this.add(first);
        }

        add(member: Member) {
            this.members.push(member);
        }

        logMembers() {
            for (var member in this.members) {
                console.log(member);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

app.js

```
///<reference path="memberDB.ts"/>
var db = MemberDB.Database;
var Frank = {
    name: "Frank Arne",
    age: 38,
    hobbies: ['Baking', 'Swimming']
}

db.add(Frank);
db.logMembers();
```

When I try to run app.js with node, I get this error:

```
/Users/.../js/app.js:2
var db = new MemberDB.Database;
         ^
ReferenceError: MemberDB is not defined
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/.../js/app.js:2:14)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:906:3
```

I want to separate the the MemberDB logic from app.js in its own file (memberDB.ts). Then import and make a Database object to do some work with. How can this be done? I've also tried to `import db = require('memberDB)';`, without luck.

Thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has two issues:

a.) You are using *internal modules* wrong. You need to `export` for them to get added to the module. This is explained by David's answer. But more importantly and why this answer is here:

b.) you don't need to use *internal modules* when working with *commonjs*:

Your code should be :

memberDB.ts:

```
export interface Member {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    hobbies: string[];
}

export class Database {
    private members: Member[];

    constructor(first ? : Member) {
        this.add(first);
    }

    add(member: Member) {
        this.members.push(member);
    }

    logMembers() {
        for (var member in this.members) {
            console.log(member);
        }
    }
}
```

and them *import/require* it in app.ts:

```
import memberDB = require('./memberDB');
var db = new memberDB.Database();
var Frank = {
    name: "Frank Arne",
    age: 38,
    hobbies: ['Baking', 'Swimming']
}

db.add(Frank);
db.logMembers();
```

Notice I also fixed up `db = new memberDB.Database();` for you i.e. you need to call the constructor function.

More about internal vs. external modules : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `export` keyword on both the interface and the class.
To have the class and/or the interface visible outside of the module. You need to define it like this:

```
module MemberDB {
    export interface Member {
        ...
    }

    export class Database {
        ...
    }
}
```